# A weird flutter error that i dont know how to fix

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I was following a crash course on flutter and got this weird error.

[image] terminal error display in visual studio code.

[image] Android error display

[image] main.dart

[image] answer.dart

[image] question.dart

[image] quiz.dart

[image] resullt.dart

Please remove me

```
  Future<void> _onDelete(String token) async {
    print('this is sample code');
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: Add the code to your question

Comment: The error message is very clear here.. You passing null value into a text widget... Please also include reproducible code when asking question here

Comment: yep i just added the code

Comment: @abd15 Welcome to SO... Please read how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will tells you to never add code in image format and also reason for it.. please edit your question with code in text format and format it using editor

Comment: i did try pasting the code in the first place, but it says indentation error all over that place eventhough i have 0 indentation error in the ide. Also yh i do know its a 'null value into a text widget' error but how do i fix it??

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `null` to a `Text()` widget. To avoid this error, you can either null check or you can do this to show an empty string on null: `Text(yourString ?? '');`